# Find Element under dl, dt using Selenium Webdriver, C#

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver

I'm using Selenium Webdriver 2.30 in C#.  I appreciate if someone can tell me how to get the link clicking (id="e") in the following structure.

```
<frame name = "a">
    #document
        <html>
            <head></head>
            <body>
                <div id = "b">
                    <dl id= "c">
                        <dt class = "d">
                            <a href = "http://somewhere.com" id = "e" class> Go to somewhere</a>
                        </dt>
                        <dt>
                            <a href = "http://something.com" id = "f"> Find something </a>
                        </dt>
                    </dl>
                </div>
            </body>
        </html>     
</frame>
```

I tried

```
selenium.SwitchTo().Frame("a");
selenium.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[@id=\"e\"]")).Click();
```

And tried

```
selenium.SwitchTo().Frame("a");
selenium.FindElement(By.XPath("//div[@id='b']/dl[1]/dt[1]/a")).Click();
```

I also tried

```
selenium.SwitchTo().Frame("a");
selenium.FindElement(By.LinkText("Go to somewhere")).Click();
```

Unfortunately, none of them works.  The problem might because there is something different for element under a definition list, but I've not figured out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception messages thrown might useful here, post if you can.

First you need to make sure it's in the correct frame.
Try debug the following and see if the counts are correct.

```c#
selenium.SwitchTo().Frame("a");
IList<IWebElement> dt = selenium.FindElements(By.XPath("//div[@id='b']//dt"));

// alternative way
selenium.SwitchTo().Frame(selenum.FindElement(By.CssSelector("frame[name='a']")));
IList<IWebElement> dt = selenium.FindElements(By.CssSelector("#b dt"));
```

If the it's in the correct frame, use Firebug to validate the xpath or cssSelector. I would try the followings as well. Remember to make sure elements are actually loaded. [WebdriverWait](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-and-implicit-waits) might be useful.

```c#
selenium.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#e")).Click();
selenium.FindElement(By.CssSelector("dt.d>a")).Click();
selenium.FindElement(By.XPath("//a[text()='Go to somewhere']")).Click();
selenium.FindElement(By.XPath("(//dl[@id='c']/dt/a)[1]")).Click();
```

Comment: Thanks buddy.  My team lead helped to figure out the problem.  Because I have another Swithto Frame before this one.  So it was actually failed on the swithto Frame("a").  The solution is so easy as add selenium.Navigate().Refresh(); before switchto frame.  From my understanding, after doing a switchto frame, the webdriver will ignore other frames unless you do a page refresh.

Comment: No, `selenium.Navigate().Refresh();` might work, but it is not the desirable and intended way to handle this issue. If you want jump out the frame, you should use `selenium.SwitchTo().DefaultContent()` [see ITargetLocator.cs#67](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/dotnet/src/WebDriver/ITargetLocator.cs#67). This will let webdriver switch back, and then you use another `selenium.SwitchTo().Frame();`. By the way, free feel to upvote and select my answer as accepted answer if you found it helpful and solved your issue.