# How to get text same level tags with selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

```html
<div id="mw-content-text">
  <p title="Meanings"   style="margin-bottom: 0.5em;">
    Meanings
  </p>
  <dl>
    <dd>
       data1
    </dd>
  </dl>
  <p title="Idioms">
    Idioms
  </p>
  <dl>
    <dd>
      data2
    </dd>
   </dl>
 </div>
```

I want to insert data1 and data2 into different arraylist with selenium. How can I do?

Comment: Did you check these questions? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15954780/find-element-under-dl-dt-using-selenium-webdriver-c-sharp and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11521602/selenium-get-element-class-and-text

Comment: I checked these question and not working. Actually problem is "dl dont include id or class or something." When I get text from 'mw-content-text' , data1 and data2 come together. I cann't divide data1 and data2.

Comment: Use a selector like #mw-content-text dd  to find all elements and loop trough them and save the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the title attribute of the p tag is always present and consistent.

Using CSS

```
"div[id='mw-content-text'] > p[title='Meanings'] + dl>dd"
"div[id='mw-content-text'] > p[title='Idioms'] + dl>dd"
```

Using Xpath

```
"//div[@id='mw-content-text']/p[@title='Meanings']/following-sibling::dl[1]/dd"
"//div[@id='mw-content-text']/p[@title='Idioms']/following-sibling::dl[1]/dd"
```

Comment: You can slightly simplify the CSS selector as, `#mw-content-text > p[title='Meanings'] + dl > dd` and so on.

Comment: thanks, It works succesfully. Can I ask another question ? Meanings include a lot of data . For example; Assumming that meanings include data1,data2,data3 and Idioms include data4,data5,data6. I get only Idioms without any problems but when I want to get only meanings(data1,data2,data3),selenium give me all datas (data1 , data2 ,data3 ,data4 ,data5,data6).How can I fix tihs?

Comment: I write this code:
List<WebElement> elements = getWebDriver().findElements(By.xpath("//div[@id='mw-content-text']/p[@title='Meanings']/following-sibling::dl/dd"));

Comment: You have to put in the [1] after dl for the 'meanings'. In the sample code you are missing that. If you use CSS instead you do not need to add [1].